# Error: Unsupported Frame Type Puppeteer Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, puppeteer

I have a project for web automation, i created this project using:

- `Puppeteer v21.9.0`
- `Typescript v5.3.3`
- `NodeJS v20.9.0`
- `Chrome Browser v121.0.6167.85`
- `OS: Ubuntu 22.04`

I want to click a button, the button is located inside the frameset and frame.

I follow instruction from the documentation https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.frame

But after i tried that, it throw error `Error: Unsupported frame type`

Here's the dummy html code which similar to the original one on the page

`index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <frameset rows="100%">
    <frame frameborder="0" />
    <frame src="test.html" frameborder="0" name="mainframe" />
  </frameset>
</html>
```

And here the `test.html`

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="button" class="close-popup">Click Me</button>
  </body>

  <script>
    const buttonClick = document
      .getElementById("button")
      .addEventListener("click", function (clicked) {
        alert("Test");
      });
  </script>
</html>
```

And this my code using puppeteer

```
import puppeteer from "puppeteer"
(async () => {
  try {
    console.log("test")
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: false
    })
    

    const page = await browser.newPage()
  
    await page.goto("http://127.0.0.1:5500/index.html")

    const mainFrame = page
      .frames()
      .find((frame) => frame.name() === "mainframe");

    if (mainFrame) {
      const closeButtonSelector = ".close-popup";
      await mainFrame.waitForSelector(closeButtonSelector, { visible: true });
      await mainFrame.click(closeButtonSelector);
      console.log("Successfully clicked the close button in the main frame.");
    } else {
      console.log("Frame not found.");
    }
  }catch(error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
})();
```

But, after i tried that code, it `throw error` like this

```
Error: Unsupported frame type
    at CdpElementHandle.#clickableBox (/home/rifqi/Projects/auto-puppeteer/node_modules/puppeteer-core/src/api/ElementHandle.ts:1088:15)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async CdpElementHandle.clickablePoint (/home/rifqi/Projects/auto-puppeteer/node_modules/puppeteer-core/src/api/ElementHandle.ts:707:17)
    at async CdpElementHandle.<anonymous> (/home/rifqi/Projects/auto-puppeteer/node_modules/puppeteer-core/src/api/ElementHandle.ts:164:16)
    at async CdpElementHandle.click (/home/rifqi/Projects/auto-puppeteer/node_modules/puppeteer-core/src/api/ElementHandle.ts:748:20)
    at async CdpElementHandle.<anonymous> (/home/rifqi/Projects/auto-puppeteer/node_modules/puppeteer-core/src/api/ElementHandle.ts:167:22)
    at async CdpFrame.click (/home/rifqi/Projects/auto-puppeteer/node_modules/puppeteer-core/src/api/Frame.ts:1053:5)
```

### Updated 6 February 2024:

It is bug from puppeteer. See https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/11827

The latest version of puppeteer work fine for handling frameset is  `v.21.1.0`

Comment: Can you share the page and a [mcve] so the code is runnable?

Comment: Sorry, I can't share the page due the restrictions and confidentiality, but i can share the dummy code similar to the original one on the page. I will edit the post

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).